# using "if else" conditionals with Channel Images

Tags: devdemon, channel-images

I'm trying to make a "previous" button link dependent on a couple of conditions: 1) if there's a previous image, it links to that; 2) if there is no previous image, it goes to the main portfolio page. Here's my basic code:

```
{image:paginate}
        {if image:previous_page}<a href="{image:auto_path}">
        {if:else}<a href="{site_url}portfolio">{/if}
            <img src="{site_url}images/arrow-back.png" alt="previous"></a>
{/image:paginate}
```

But when I try this, I get an error code:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE....
```

Any thoughts on either what's wrong or how to do this properly?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: It looks like devdemon's fault. Are eecms and channel images up to date?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what the problem is now. I looked more closely at the documentation, and for the `{image:previous_page}` tag it says

> This tag will conditionally display the code inside the tag if there is a “previous” page. If there is no previous page then the content simply will not be displayed. (In the {image:paginate} tag pair)

So I think since there is no "previous" page, then the `{if:else}` part is not displayed (at least this is my theory). So what I've done to make this work is this:

```
{image:paginate}
    {if image:previous_page}<a href="{image:auto_path}">{/if}
    {if {image:current_page} == 1}<a href="{site_url}portfolio">{/if}
        <img src="{site_url}images/arrow-back.png" alt="previous"></a>
{/image:paginate}
```

This is working for me. I do recall at some point that `{if:else}` was just not working in Channel Images, and when I was pursuing the question some time ago, there was never a resolution. I don't know if `{if:else}` will work now in Channel Images or not (I have 5.14.8). But with the new support system from DevDemon, I'd have to pay to find out.